# Is it possible to change a popup's HTML in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to integrate "pinning" functionality into my OpenLayers popups.  Right now, when the user clicks on a "pin" image I've placed inside a popup, I want the source to toggle between the `pinned.png` image and an `unpinned.png` image.

I'm trying to do so like this:

```
var pHtml = marker.feature.data.popupContentHTML;
marker.feature.data.popupContentHTML = pHtml.replace("pinned.png", "unpinned.png");
```

This seems to change the popupContentHTML variable (because when I console.log it, the "pinned.png" has been replaced with "unpinned.png" for the marker), but the HTML on-screen does not change.

Is there an easier way to do this, or is there a way to refresh the popup to display the new popupContentHTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a setter function for the HTML content that also updates the DOM element for the popup. It's called [`setContentHTML`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html#OpenLayers.Popup.setContentHTML).